# Create Date object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have two strings Date and Time. I am using Javascript. I want to create a date object with date and time. I have converted date and time to UTC format. Like, if you take current date 27th Oct, then Date format is

```
    Tues Oct 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

and if you select time 1PM then time format is

```
    13:00:00
```

I want to create a Date object using Javascript where, I will submit Date and Time and it will create a Date object like

```
    Tues Oct 27 2015 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to AngularJS. So I would remove that out of the title, and also make the title more clear.

Comment: Yeah, Javascript related only. I have edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Date prototype's constructor to create a date from a specified point in time.

The order of the constructor's arguments are easy enough:

- year
- month (warning: starts at 0)
- day
- hour
- minute
- second
- milliseconds

So to create `Tues Oct 27 2015 13:00:00 GMT+0530`, you would use this constructor:

```
var myDate = new Date(2015, 9, 27, 13, 0, 0, 0);
```

The rest of the information you need can be found in the JavaScript Date documentation, available for example on the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Suppose, my date is in date variable and time is in time variable. So, if I write var myDate = new Date(date, time); Then it will work?

Comment: No, not that easily. To help you I need to know in what format is your "date variable" and "time variable"? Are they strings? Structures?

Comment: I have done it, by using setTime ( ).

Answer (score -1):

Just have a look at the javascript Date object documentation 
There you will find you answer

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: Can I humbly suggest you read [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: My Date is already taking a null time value 00:00:00 and I am generating time separately. Now, I need to replace the null time value of date with my generated UTC time.

Comment: @Jamiec im referring to pages that could possibly help him with his problem. I'm quite new here so excuse me for not answering correct

Comment: I appreciate that, which is why I attempted to help you help others. It was not meant as an insult (hence the "humbly" part! Plus newer users often wonder why their seemingly good answer gets downvoted))

Comment: Ok ok.....well thanks for the advice :)